# Isometries are affine transformations

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I want to show that, if $(M,\mathrm{g})$ is a Riemannian manifold, $\nabla$ is the covariant derivative from the Levi-Civita connection, and $f:M\to M$ is an isometry, then $f_*(\nabla_XY)=\nabla_{f_*X}f_*Y$. I can demonstrate that this works if I resort to coordinate expressions, but I don't want to do that.

At first, I thought to use the fact that $\nabla$ is metric, so that $$\nabla_Zf^*\mathrm{g}(X,Y)=\mathrm{g}(f_*(\nabla_ZX),f_*Y)+\mathrm{g}(f_*X,f_*(\nabla_ZY))=\mathrm{g}(\nabla_ZX,Y)+\mathrm{g}(X,\nabla_ZY),$$ but I can't seem to get anywhere with it.

Any hints as to how I might approach this?

Comment: What definition of "isometry" are you using?

Comment: @JackLee In this case, isometry means $f^*\mathrm{g}=\mathrm{g}$.

Comment: You also need to assume that $f$ is a diffeomorphism, because otherwise $f_*$ need not push vector fields forward to vector fields. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $f\colon M\to M$ is a diffeomorphism satisfying $f^*g  = g$.

It's not enough just to use the fact that $\nabla$ is a metric connection; you also have to use the fact that it's torsion-free. The idea of the proof is to define $\widetilde \nabla\colon \mathfrak X(M)\times \mathfrak X(M) \to \mathfrak X(M)$ by
$$
\widetilde \nabla_XY = (f^{-1})_*(\nabla_{f_*X}{f_*Y}).
$$
Then  you can show that $\widetilde\nabla$ is a connection on $M$ that is compatible with $g$ and torsion-free. By the uniqueness of the Riemannian connection, $\widetilde \nabla$ must be equal to $\nabla$.